# Parsing unquoted SVG in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack, gatsby

I'm trying to build my Gatsby Project and I'm facing the following error:

```
Generating JavaScript bundles failed

postcss-svgo: Error in parsing SVG: Unquoted attribute value
Line: 0
Column: 12
Char: \
```

I wasn't able to find which svg may be causing this problem and `gastsby build --verbose` wasn't able to give me hints where to check

How can I discover the svg that may be causing the problem or how to change some configuration in gatsby/webpack that may solve this?

Comment: Is there any more information you can add to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`postcss-svgo` hints that a derivate of SVGO is used (https://github.com/svg/svgo).

You could run SVGO manually over your SVGs. The cli should give hints to what file may be corrupted.

Make sure you output the minified svgs into an output folder:

```
svgo ../your/svg/folder/*.svg -o ../path/to/folder/with/svg/output
```

Comment: Thanks. I did it and it didn't solve the problem. So I understood that wasn't any svg file. Investigating further I discovered that the css files I was using had svg insides. So the problem was in the svg from the css files and I just commented and was able to build the project.